# Can't build Xamarin UrhoSharp.Forms sample project in release mode

Tags: c#, android, .net, visual-studio, xamarin.android

When i'm trying to build xamarin urhosharp [sample project](https://github.com/xamarin/urho-samples/tree/master/FormsSample) "FormsSample.Droid" in release mode and i set linking to "Sdk Assemblies Only", i got an error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   Xamarin.Android.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to
>   metadata item '!!0[] System.Array::Empty()' (defined in 'Urho.Forms,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from
>   'Urho.Forms, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   could not be resolved. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to
>   resolve !!0[] System.Array::Empty() at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference) at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction) at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body) at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method) at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue() at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process() at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context) at
>   Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context) at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext&
>   context) at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Xamarin.Android.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException,
>   String message, Object[] args) at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute() at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
>   FormsSample.Droid

When i set linking to "None" everything works perfectly but generated *.apk file is really big.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Answer which i got from Xamarin Member:

> It's a known issue. Should be fixed in the next nuget update. Also I'd
>   recommend to use "generate APK per ABI" option cause UrhoSharp has 5
>   native libs - ~7-14mb each.